# How do I filter several datasets in columns?

Tags: r

I'm trying to filter two different data from the same column.

`filtered_data <- filter(data, tailnum == "N76515")`

I would also like to filter N76516. What is the code for that.

I've tried with

`"N76515", "N76516"` but that didn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `filter(data, tailnum %in% c("N76515", "N76516"))`

Comment: What happened, when you say "that didn't work"?